# Как вывести отдельный параметр из таблицы .describe()

Tags: python, pandas

Весь вопрос в заголовке. Необходимо вывести отдельно среднее и стандартное отклонение из таблицы после применения функции `.describe()`
По типу

```
print('Стандартное отклонение:', ***[что сюда вставить]*** )
```

[image: Таблица]

Answer (score 1):

Ответ до безумия простой.

```
describe['minutes'][2]
```

Я ставил наоборот из-за этого и ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Проще и правильнее будет обращаться по наименованию, в зависимости от того, что вам требуется.

```
df.describe().loc['mean']
```

либо несколько

```
df.describe().loc[['mean', 'std']]
```

если к одному столбцу

```
df['minutes'].describe().loc[['mean', 'std']]
```